# QT Get Last known location quickly

Tags: android, c++, ios, qt, gps

I am developing cross platform application using QT for Android,iOS,windows. I want to get device current location. I am using [Qt Positioning Api](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtpositioning-index.html). I have written C++ code using the [Samples available](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtpositioning-logfilepositionsource-example.html). Application want to update device location at specified time interval(x seconds) or specified distance(y meters) in meters. Please find the bellow sample code written. Code is causing lot of battery drain almost 9% of the entire battery life also takes lot of time to update first location if network is off.As requirement is to update device location continuously at specified time interval, can't stop location updates [QGeoPositionInfoSource](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgeopositioninfosource.html)

**Locationhandler.h**

```
#ifndef LOCATIONHANDLER_H
#define LOCATIONHANDLER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QGeoPositionInfo>
#include <QGeoPositionInfoSource>
#include <QDebug>
#include "main.h"


class LocationHandler : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public :
    explicit LocationHandler(QObject *parent = 0);
    QGeoCoordinate getCurrentLocation();
    private :
    QGeoCoordinate currentLocation;
    QGeoPositionInfoSource *source;
    signals :
    public slots :
    void positionUpdated(const QGeoPositionInfo &info);
};
#endif // LOCATIONHANDLER_H
```

**locationhandler.cpp**

```
#include "LocationHandler.h"

LocationHandler::LocationHandler(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    source = QGeoPositionInfoSource::createDefaultSource(this);
   if (source) {
       connect(source, SIGNAL(positionUpdated(QGeoPositionInfo)),
                        this, SLOT(positionUpdated(QGeoPositionInfo)));
       source->startUpdates();
       source->setUpdateInterval(60);

   }
}

void LocationHandler::positionUpdated(const QGeoPositionInfo &info)
{
      if(info.isValid())
      {
          currentLocation = info.coordinate();
          qDebug() << "Current Latitude : " << currentLocation.latitude();
          qDebug() << "Current Longitude : " << currentLocation.longitude();
          updateDeviceCordinate(currentLocation);
      }
}
```

please let me know,

1. Is there any way where i can specify the GPS update interval in
   terms of Time and Distance which can reduce CPU active time.
2. Also I want to know is there any direct way where i can get device
   location directly using QT API without any(QT Signal) callback
   function quickly.

**Note :** qml based location update may not be helpful as we want to implement functionality in C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way where i can specify the GPS update interval in terms
>   of Time and Distance which can reduce CPU active time.

In order to know the distance/position change you have to update your `QGeoPositionInfo info`. This would contradict to your goal of reducing GPS requests/updates. However if your `QGeoPositionInfo info` also contains velocity and/or acceleration you might predict the next position change and thus avoid additional GPS requests.

> Also I want to know is there any direct way where i can get device
>   location directly using QT API without any(QT Signal) callback
>   function quickly.

You have to go somehow low-level for this which means "speak" directly to your GPS receiver.

So my advice is: if too frequent requests cost battery life, make the interval of requests variable in dependency on the predictability of the next position change.